# Remove single fragment from backstack Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I am struggling to remove a single fragment that I add dynamically when I have multiple fragments.

For examples:
MainActivty
Inflate FragA
Inflate FragB
Inflate FragC

Now how do I just delete fragment A?

Using popBackStack kills all three and  `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(TAG).commit();` also seems to do thae same thing

How are you meant to do this correctly? I am trying to keep multiple backstacks persistent over tabs

Answer (score 0):

try this...

get current fragment title & check fragment A or not.

get current fragment title to use getTitle() Method and check

```
  if(getTitle().toString.equals(fragment A){
         // do 
    }else{
         // do 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this..

For eg. using fragment name as tag:

```
FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
```

Adding to backstack:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
ft.commit();
```

Popping:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);
```

This should only pop the fragment with the specific tag.